# How can I export chart with specific position from excel to ppt in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

```
Sheets("Slide Name").ChartObjects("Object 8").Select

Selection.Copy

   mySlide.Select
```

The datatype is `ppPasteOLEObject`, not `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`,

```
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, _
       Link:=msoTrue
```

Below code is not working.

```
   Set myShapeRange = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

      myShapeRange.Left = 234
      myShapeRange.Top = 186
```

How can i select the specific chart in PowerPoint and reposition it?

Answer (score 0):

This short test just works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim objSlide As Slide
    Dim objPresentation As Presentation
    Dim objShape As Shape
    Dim objApplication As Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet

    Set objApplication = New Excel.Application
    Set objWorkbook = objApplication.Workbooks.Open("c:\@Test\Chart.xlsx")
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set objPresentation = ActivePresentation
    Set objSlide = objPresentation.Slides(1)
    objWorksheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Select

    objApplication.Selection.Copy

    objSlide.Select
    objSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue

    Set objShape = objSlide.Shapes(objSlide.Shapes.Count)
    objShape.Left = 100
    objShape.Top = 100
End Sub
```

You can have a breakpoint when getting shape object and give it a try in watch. The paste operation always adds a new item to the end of the list.